# Flex AS3 - Custom buttons

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, button

I need some input..
What would be the best (well, recommended) way to implement custom buttons inside Flash Builder?

What I mean by custom buttons, is that I need to show for example a building with 5 floors (in 3d view). The user can then click each of the floor, to update the main view to show the currently selected floor.

In previous examples I've simply added one invisible layer below the image, which contains one solid color for each button (each floor). Clicking the image triggers a function that checks what color is selected, and then triggers the action I want.

Are there any better ways of doing this?

Maybe importing an external SWF that communicates with the main app to send the floor-switching commands? (Not that I know how to communicate from an imported external SWF to the main app, only the other way around).

Any input would be great =)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

*After your question, I whipped up something quickly to show that buttons can be of any shape.  If you want the floors to be selectable, then you probably want a `ToggleButton`, not a `Button` so I have re-worked my example a bit and the result is what you described*

[image]

Why not use the Flex 4.0 Skinning capability?  You get the behavior (and states) of the button component with your own look/feel:

```
<s:ToggleButton skinClass="FloorButton" y="0"  />
<s:ToggleButton skinClass="FloorButton" y="25" />
<s:ToggleButton skinClass="FloorButton" y="50" />
```

You define your button skin (`FloorButton`) with some images:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SparkButtonSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009"
                   alpha.disabledStates="0.5">

    <fx:Metadata>
    <![CDATA[ 
        [HostComponent("spark.components.ToggleButton")]
    ]]>
    </fx:Metadata>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="up" />
        <s:State name="over" stateGroups="overStates" />
        <s:State name="down" stateGroups="downStates" />
        <s:State name="disabled" stateGroups="disabledStates" />
        <s:State name="upAndSelected" stateGroups="selectedStates, selectedUpStates" />
        <s:State name="overAndSelected" stateGroups="overStates, selectedStates" />
        <s:State name="downAndSelected" stateGroups="downStates, selectedStates" />
        <s:State name="disabledAndSelected" stateGroups="selectedUpStates, disabledStates, selectedStates" />
    </s:states>

    <s:Path data="M 0 0 L 20 20 L 40 0 L 40 20 L 20 40 L 0 20">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="#AAAAAA" color.selectedStates="#000000" color.over="#777777" />
        </s:fill>
    </s:Path>

</s:SparkButtonSkin>
```

Of course, the path can be replaced with a PNG with transparency to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to make the buttons "non-square"? I need to use, say, 5 floors seen from a 3D side-view. And the ability to click any of these.

Comment: Yes.  You can make your button any shape you want.

Comment: Like this. Each floor is a button that triggers the BG to change.
I'll take a look at your code =)
http://i48.tinypic.com/vytc92.jpg

Comment: @StianBergLarsen Indeed.  I have edited my response to be more like your suggestion.  Good luck.

Comment: I'll read through it in a sec. Did a quick test with the previous code you posted, but the buttons flicker.. In this example, I have 3 buttons placed partly on top of each other.
http://screencast.com/t/XGDXWdHOhORl

Comment: @StianBergLarsen From the looks of it, your hover state is not properly yielding an image and you are toggling between hovered and normal.  You also might try two images with the `includeIn="over"` and `excludeFrom="hover"`.

Comment: The flickering is gone now, but I still cant seem to get the hit-area working properly. It's defined as a rectangle around the .pgn image, even though I have transparent background... Any ideas?

Comment: Right... because the PNG is clickable no matter what.  OK, so, you can try to make the PNG disabled (`enabled="false"`) and then draw a path with a .01 alpha fill on top of it for the hit area... or you can try this: http://www.webverwirklichung.com/en/blog/programming/flex/creating-hitarea-png-image-transparent-alpha-regions-flex

Comment: Thanks. I ended up just learning to use the Path and draw the buttons like you did in the example :) Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

When youre working with flex then why don`t use the flex components and skin them?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://rabidgadfly.com/2010/09/easily-create-image-buttons-flex-4/) tutorial on how to do button skinning in Flex 4 goes through the process step by step.

Flex 4 also enables easy-to-implement [3d effects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSF0D55C84-17E0-456a-A977-04BFE1E23BA8.html) (which you mentioned in your question).

Comment: I think it's v4 I'm using now =) I'll read through the articles!
Thanks

Comment: I followed the tutorial you posted, but the hit-area is always a rectangle. I need to stack 3-6 buttons on top of each other (each looks like 1 floor of a building). Any ideas? I'll go through the above post again and see if I missed something.

Comment: I don't think I can add to Brian Genisio's updated answer. It's excellent and helps you create the look you want.